# SVG-Pan-Zoom on DOM Object tag not working

Tags: javascript, svg, svgpanzoom

I have an `<object>` where I load an external svg file:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="system.svg" id="Graph_Container" class="GraphContainmentArea">
    Your browser does not support SVG 
</object>
```

I am using the SVG pan and zoom functionality of the following library: https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom. However, simply adding the `svg-pan-zoom.js` file to my page seems to not be sufficient in adding any kind of functionality to the svg contained in the `object` with the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<iw:iwidget id="GraphContainer" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:iw="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/iWidget" supportedModes="view edit"
 lang="en" iScope="GraphContainerScope" title="Graph Container Widget">

<iw:content mode="view">
        <![CDATA[     
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Widgets/GraphContainerWidget/css/graphcontainer.css" />
            <script src="/Widgets/GraphContainerWidget/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div id="GraphContainer_IWID_" class="search-area" style="display:block;">
                <div class="content-area" id="content-area_IWID_">
                    <div class="RightPanel" id="rightPanel_IWID_">
                        <table id='main-content_IWID_' class="links-included">
                            <tr>
                                <object type="image/svg+xml" data="" id="_IWID_Graph_Container" class="GraphContainmentArea">
                                    Your browser does not support SVG 
                                </object>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td></td></tr>
                            <tr><td></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="_IWID_Graph_Footer" class="FooterContainmentArea">Optional Footer</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <div id='footer_IWID_' class="footer">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/Widgets/GraphContainerWidget/js/svg-pan-zoom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var _IWID_attributesItemSet = iContext.getiWidgetAttributes();
    var _IWID_iDescriptor = iContext.getiDescriptor();

    var SVG_GRAPH_URL = _IWID_attributesItemSet.getItemValue("wid_import_field");
    var SVG_FOOTER = _IWID_attributesItemSet.getItemValue("wid_footer_field");
    var SVG_MULTI = _IWID_attributesItemSet.getItemValue("wid_multigraphs_field");

        console.log("Viewmode SRC URL: " + SVG_GRAPH_URL);
try {
    if (SVG_GRAPH_URL !== null && SVG_GRAPH_URL !== "") {
        var finished_URL = httpcheck() + SVG_GRAPH_URL;
        $("#Graph_Container").attr("data", finished_URL);

        setTimeout(function() {
            svgPanZoom("#_IWID_Graph_Container", {
                zoomEnabled: true,
                controlIconsEnabled: true
            });
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        alert("No URL passed to graph container!")
    }
}
catch(e) {
    console.log(e.name + "-" + e.description + "-" + e.message);
}

function httpcheck() {
    if (SVG_GRAPH_URL.substring(0,7) == "http://" || SVG_GRAPH_URL.substring(0,8) == "https://") {
        return "";
    } else {
        return "http://";
    }
}

    </script>
    ]]>
</iw:content>
```

Note: jQuery is the only library I'm using other than SVG-Pan-Zoom.js
Any tips on how I can address this issue/improve the code?
The current error I get is `svgPan is not defined`.

**Above code updated**

Comment: You probably do not include the right javascript file in your HTML if you are using "Node.js" (with likely routes), maybe it's a flaw in your local server configuration.

Comment: I included the javascript file that the author linked in the instructions. It shouldn't an issue with server because the `svg` is loaded completely and the flag I put around the needed code is being hit after the load.

Comment: when I say "issue in server" I refer to loading the javascript file trough a route. Analysis "network tab" in your web-browser.

Comment: The javascript is loading fine. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/lbwmmCa.png)

Comment: I download [svg-pan-zoom](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom/master/dist/svg-pan-zoom.js), but not found `svgPan` variable/method

In other worlds, maybe you are calling `svgPan` or create an variable with this name.

When you call this variable/method invalidates it crash the whole script that comes after and not run for this reason is not a problem with the LIB, but something you might have added, post the entire code please.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Code updated

Comment: Thanks, but when I say "entire code" I refer "entire html" + "entire js". I wait, thanks again. –  Guilherme Nascimento 29 mins ago

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento code added

Comment: `iContext` is undefined, try post an example of your issue in http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: It's not really relevant to the question lol. iContext is a way of getting cached values and _IWID_ is the unique ID of the widget

Comment: it is a matter of *relevance*. the question is able to *reproduce the problem* so we can help you. if you provide something that already demonstrates the failure without people who see you need help fix other flaws, sure you will get faster and better answers.

Comment: Managed to replicate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/c3d0bp3q/

Comment: You no added *svg-pan-zoom.js* in "External Resources"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to determine the cause of your problem, because their example *may not be reproduced*.

> Note: I tested ["svg-pan-zoom"](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom) on a my application and it worked normally.

### Possible reasons for your problem:

1. **SVG** and **your page** requires work in "same domain" or support to
   ["CORS"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).
2. You are using ["file URI scheme"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme), but this causes a problem with secure in "Web Browser"
3. Can be a problem in time to clone the repository.

### Solutions

1. For problem with cross-origin (CORS) read this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
2. For problem with "file URI", I recommend install ["Xampp" (Apache and PHP)](https://www.apachefriends.org) and ["Node.js"](http://nodejs.org/) for use ["HTTP localhost"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)
3. For problems with "git download" you need to either `git clone --recursive git@github.com:ariutta/svg-pan-zoom.git` or if you already cloned it, then `git submodule update --init --recursive`

### Example width "data URI"

> Note: Work only in Firefox, because in Chrome *"data URI scheme"* no sends *"origin header"*
>
> Note: For work in Chrome use "http URI scheme" for load your SVG
>
> Note: I used "data URI" because jsfiddle don't support to send "resources"

```
<script src="svg-pan-zoom.js"></script>
<object type="image/svg+xml" id="svgId" data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
    Your browser does not support SVG or not loaded (Work only in Gecko - Firefox) 
</object>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    svgPanZoom("#svgId", {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        controlIconsEnabled: true
    });
};
</script>
```

Online example: http://jsfiddle.net/L4u6ap2w/

Comment: The git instructions mention that it works with SVG embedded in `<object>` tags, maybe help me by showing an example of this in fiddle?

Comment: @Xenyal I believe it can be an problem during the you are cloning the repository to your machine.